# TFS: does not exist at the specified version

Tags: tfs

I've got a file in Visual Studio TFS that was deleted my one of my teammates while I was doing a merge. When I try to check in the merged/deleted file, I get a dialog that it was checked in because there were conflicts.  The Pending Changes - Conflicts tap doesn't show any conflicts but the Output windows has the following message:

"The item $/.../Reference.cs does not exist at the specified version."

When I try to undo the changes, I get an error that says "Sql Error: 515"

So I can't check in the file and I can't undo the changes.

I'd be OK with remvoing the file altogether or adding back to source control. I just want it out of my pending changes list.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting situation.

The quick fix might be to just undelete the file within TFS.

1. Go to Tools | Options.
2. Expand Source Control and select "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server"
3. Enable the "Show deleted items in the Source Control Explorer" window.
4. Go to that file undelete it.
5. Try to undo again or continue the merge.